# Rails searches the wrong database for model data when using multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an application in Rails which requires me to access multiple SQL databases. The resources I found online suggested I use `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`, however, this seems to interfere with my site's models. After connecting to a different database, when I next do `<model>.<command>`, it gives me `Mysql2::Error: Table '<Database I had to access through establish_connection>.<Model's table>' doesn't exist` eg: `Mysql2::Error: Table 'test.words' doesn't exist` , which means rails tries to look for the table associated with its models in the database I had to access through `establish_connection` instead of the site development database.

## Steps to reproduce error:

Here are some steps I found which seem to reproduce the problem;

First, I create a new rails app:

```
rails new sqldbtest -d mysql
cd sqldbtest
```

Then I set the config file:

```
default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8mb4
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
username: root
password: <omitted>
host: localhost
```

Then create a controller, model, and some data in the mysql database:

```
rails generate controller test test
rails generate model Word name:string txt:text
rails db:create
rails db:migrate
rails c
cat=Word.new
cat.name="Cat"
cat.txt="Cat."
cat.save
exit
mysql -u root -p # I already have a database called "test".
use test;
create table extst (id int primary key, name varchar(8), txt text);
insert into extst (id,name,txt) values (0,"Bob","Bob.");
quit
```

I then made the controller and the view:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
def test
itemOne=Word.find_by(name:"Cat")
@textOne=itemOne.txt
con=ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'mysql2', encoding: 'utf8mb4', username: 'root', password: <omitted>, host: 'localhost', database: 'test').connection
@textTwo=con.execute('select txt from extst where name="Bob"').to_a[0][0]
end
end
```

I wrote this in the view:

```
<%= @textOne %><br>
<%= @textTwo %>
```

added 'root "test#test"' to config/routes.rb

```
rails s
```

## Result:

When I load the page, it shows "Cat." and "Bob." on separate lines as expected, but when I refresh, It shows the error as described above.

I have tried adding `con.close` to the controller, but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since this error comes from making a connection to another database, adding `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'mysql2', encoding: 'utf8mb4', username: 'root', password: <omitted>, host: 'localhost', database: 'sqldbtest_development').connection` to the controller after `@textTwo=con.execute('select txt from extst where name="Bob"').to_a[0][0]` stops the error from happening, however I don't know if this is the best practice or if it has any side effrcts. For example, the database will need to be changed when moving to test or production.

This solution is most likely just a temporary workaround.